# Modals inside a Carousel

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, styled-components

I'm trying to create a carousel of modals. Each modal represent a product and has a picture and data. when the user clicks on the picture the modal opens. I build the modal with [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components), and the carousel is [@brainhubeu/react-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@brainhubeu/react-carousel) (I tried a lot of carousel packages and I failed at each).

The modal itself is working as expected but when I insert the modal into the carousel the modal stops working and i can't find how to resolve the problem.

The modal code is

```
// Background Behind the modal
const Background = styled.div`
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity: ${props => (props.open ? "1" : "0")};
  visibility: ${props => (props.open ? "visible" : "hidden")};
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out 0s, visibility 0.3s ease-out 0s;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
`;

//Modal
const Modal = styled.div`
  z-index: 4;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out 0s;
  will-change: transform;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
  width: 80vw;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  transform: ${props =>
    props.open ? "translate(-50% ,-50%)" : "translateY(0%)"};
  visibility: ${props => (props.open ? "visible" : "hidden")};
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) -2px 2px 4px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
`;

const ModalBuilder = props => {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false); // change state for opening and closing the modal
  return (
    <div>
      <Background onClick={() => setModalShow(false)} open={modalShow} />
      <Image src={props.data.avatar} alt="modal image" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)} />
      <Modal className="modal-window" open={modalShow}>{/*modal content*/}</Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ModalBuilder;
```

also check [my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-carousel-721l9?file=/src/Modal.js). i added an example of the modal itself under the carousel.

thank you very much

Comment: I haven't really read a lot into code shared by you, but I would want you to think of it from a design perspective. Modal is for a very different user story / user emotion. Its part of the feedback mechanism. However Carousel, on the other hand, is more of a display component. You should not mix both of them together.

Comment: @AshishSingh I didn't  understand. From my point of view both of them are display component. the modal is a nice display for each product and the carousel is display component for for a nice view of bunch of products (Instead of a list of products).
thanks